# My tekkit classic keeps crashing!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-tekkit, minecraft-technic-pack

I was playing Tekkit classic when I got horrible lag, so I did what I always do I closed it and opened it again. Then when the mojang screen came up my tekkit crashed and I haven't been able to open it since.

```
Generated 6/21/14 9:37 AM

Minecraft: Minecraft 1.2.5
OS: Mac OS X (x86_64) version 10.8.5
Java: 1.6.0_65, Apple Inc.
VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Apple Inc.
LWJGL: 2.9.0
OpenGL: Intel HD Graphics 3000 OpenGL Engine version 2.1 INTEL-8.16.77, Intel Inc.

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.modloader.ModLoaderModContainer.init(ModLoaderModContainer.java:356)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.modInit(Loader.java:273)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.initializeMods(Loader.java:628)
    at cpw.mods.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.onLoadComplete(FMLClientHandler.java:223)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.a(Minecraft.java:429)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:738)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is [requesting **technical support for a modded Minecraft crash issue**](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10390/4797). We allow an exception for unmodded or 'Vanilla' Minecraft, please see [How do I ask a good Minecraft Bug/Crash Question?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/9943/4797)

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me (as a Java programmer) that a core mod has been corrupted or is not working properly. Fix it by:

1. Make a backup of your world files by typing %appdata% into windows explorer, then go to Roaming -> .technic -> tekkit -> saves. Copy the world files to a safe location. (If you use a texture pack, make sure you back that up as well.)
2. Delete all files in the tekkit folder
3. Launch the Technic Launcher and scroll to tekkit classic.
4. Click Play. At this point Tekkit will download all of the mod files again.
5. Copy your world files back into tekkit/saves. (And texture packs back into tekkit/texturepacks.)
6. Load the world and play again.